# Getting error while extracting text from Image with type 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile' using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

trying to extract text from image whose type is `'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'` using `pytesseract`. The code and the error is as below

```py
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('D:/pdf_csv/HealthCare/eRDS - ML/eRDS - ML/2001468/2001468,69,70.pdf',poppler_path='C:/Users/Hp/poppler-0.68.0/bin')
text = pyt.image_to_string(Image.open(pages[0]), lang='eng')
```

Error I am getting:

```py
AttributeError: 'PpmImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Or Is there any method to convert the PpmImageFile to 'jpg' or 'png' format

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You don't need to open, because it's already opened. 
Just remove Image.open
pyt.image_to_string(pages[0])

Answer (score 4):

Add `fmt='jpeg'` or `fmt='png'` to your function call to get non-PPM images from pdf2image.

In you example, change

```
pages = convert_from_path('D:/pdf_csv/Health....001468,69,70.pdf',poppler_path='C:/Users/Hp/poppler-0.68.0/bin')
```

to

```
pages = convert_from_path('D:/pdf_csv/Health...001468,69,70.pdf', fmt='jpeg', poppler_path='C:/Users/Hp/poppler-0.68.0/bin')
```